# Converting UIImageView to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uikit, uiimage

I'm working with images, I have tonnes of them, and I'm downloading them in real time from the server, before it was really fast with the `AsyncImageView` class, but know I'm working with the custom class, that takes `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`.

**Question:** Is there any good way to convert `UIImageView` to `UIImage`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to have an UIImage to show it in an UIImageView - where is the problem?

Comment: No, I need to show UIImageView inside UIImage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you dont need to show a UIImageView inside a UIImage. Maybe you want to show a UIImageView inside another UIImageView or maybe you want to access the UIImageView's image property, which you can do with imageView.image:

```
UIImage *imageFromImageView = myImageView.image
```

or if its the image view inside another image view option:

```
[myOuterImageView addSubiew:myInnerImageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the link between `UIImage` and `UIImageView` quite right: you don't *convert* between them because one is the representation of the actual image and the other is the view that shows the image.

A UIImageView object holds a reference to a UIImage object, allowing that image to be shown on the screen. Have a look at the [UIImageView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and you will see that the  class has a property `image` (the image that the UIImageView will show), and through this property you can access the UIImage contained within a UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` is an abstraction for image data, it doesn't display anything.

`UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView` optimized for displaying an image represented by `UIImage` onscreen.

To get the `UIImage` used by the `UIImageView`, use the image property.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *theUIImageYouGot = some assignment made already;
CusstomImage *theUIImageSubclassYouWantToDisplay = [theUIImageYouGot image];
```