# ocr tesseract Bad Access

Tags: ios, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I have this code:

```
Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
tesseract.delegate = self;

[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPKRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"]; //limit search
[tesseract setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]]; //image to check

[tesseract recognize];
```

This works fine.

However, if I change the image to see the image of an UIImageVIew, then not works (EXC_BAD_ACCESS):

```
Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng+ita"];
tesseract.delegate = self;

[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPKRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"]; //limit search
[tesseract setImage:self.imageview.image]; //image to check

[tesseract recognize];
```

do you know that it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract sholud allow UIImage only.So you should convert Imageview image into UIImage and then execute.
Please try the code.

```
Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng+ita"];
tesseract.delegate = self;

[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPKRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"]; //limit search
UIImage *imageFromImageView = self.imageview.image
[tesseract setImage:imageFromImageView ]; //image to check

[tesseract recognize];
```

Comment: Refer the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500759/converting-uiimageview-to-uiimage