# Retrieving UIImage from UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, uiimageview, uiimage

I've found the solution but it is not in Swift: [Converting UIImageView to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500759/converting-uiimageview-to-uiimage)

I've even went rogue by trying to implement it in Swift by using **UnsafeMutablePointed** and had no luck.

However, pointers are typically frowned upon in Swift and it would be nice if there was a simple one-liner solution to this!

**Example Code:**

```
let test1:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test")) 
let test2 = test1.image // This fails with an error: Instance member ‘test1’ cannot be used on type ‘viewController’
```

Answer (score 8):

I highly advise you to learn about Objective-C, as that will help you greatly in finding out how to do things in iOS (Cocoa-Touch).

The solution is identical to Objective-C:

```
imageView.image
```

Comment: Doesn't work.    
let test1:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test.jpg")) 
let test2 = test1.image

Comment: @theflarenet Make sure you're using that inside a function, because it looks like the error has something to do with it not being in a function. If you are using a playground, make sure it isn't just sitting in a class/struct with no function wrapping it.

Answer (score 3):

The `UIImageView` has a property called `image` which stores its `UIImage`. So to retrieve an `UIImageView`'s image, all you need to do is access the property:

```
let myImage = imageView.image
```

That's really all there is to it.